# Does ubuntu have mouse accel? If so, how do you dissable it?

Tags: mouse

I want to have no acceleration or anything, how can I set ubuntu to the equivalence of sensitivity 6 no acceleration on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Mouse sensitivity and acceleration is often a problem if you have a high end mouse.

Take a look at this site [no mouse acceleration](http://www.techytalk.info/turn-mouse-acceleration-off-on-ubuntu-linux/), it shows you how to remove acceleration completely.